# how to remove the extra spaces in a ListView inside a NestedScrollView?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm having trouble trying to remove the extra spaces in a list inside a NestedScrollView. why the extra space despite being shrinkWrapped? how can we remove this?

[image]

```html
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: NestedScrollView(
      headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) => [
        const SliverAppBar(
          title: Text('NestedScrollView Test'),
        ),
        ResponsiveSliverCenter(
            child: Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: ListView.separated(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: 1,
              separatorBuilder: ((context, index) => const Divider()),
              itemBuilder: ((context, index) => Container(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    height: 150,
                    child: const Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.center, child: Text('Test item')),
                  ))),
        )),
      ],
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.amber,
        child: ListView.separated(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: 1,
            separatorBuilder: ((context, index) => const Divider()),
            itemBuilder: ((context, index) => Container(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  height: 200,
                  child: const Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center, child: Text('Test item')),
                ))),
      ),
    ));
  }
```

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1OmL.jpg)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1OmL.jpg)

Comment: Check my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73920673/items-in-listview-are-not-placed-at-the-top-of-the-scaffold-container/73920775#73920775), try to add `padding: EdgeInsets.zero,` to both `ListView` widgets.

Comment: what did you use for ResponsiveSliverCenter?

Comment: @eamirho3ein that's just a sliverToBoxAdapter with added responsiveness to screen width.